# Error when running a wasm filter module in an istio proxy

Tags: filter

I followed this [article](https://content.red-badger.com/resources/extending-istio-with-rust-and-webassembly) to set up my wasm module and run it using an istio proxy like this:

`wasme deploy envoy wasm_filter_intro:v0.1 --envoy-image=istio/proxyv2:1.17.3`

Unfortunately, it fails and throws this error:

```
[2023-06-11 06:51:59.701][1][info][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:408]   envoy.quic.server.crypto_stream: envoy.quic.crypto_stream.server.quiche
[2023-06-11 06:51:59.701][1][info][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:408]   envoy.guarddog_actions: envoy.watchdog.abort_action, envoy.watchdog.profile_action
[2023-06-11 06:51:59.701][1][info][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:408]   envoy.connection_handler: envoy.connection_handler.default
[2023-06-11 06:51:59.712][1][critical][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:131] error initializing configuration '': Protobuf message (type envoy.config.bootstrap.v3.Bootstrap reason INVALID_ARGUMENT:(static_resources.clusters[0]) tlsContext: Cannot find field.) has unknown fields
[2023-06-11 06:51:59.712][1][info][main] [external/envoy/source/server/server.cc:972] exiting
Protobuf message (type envoy.config.bootstrap.v3.Bootstrap reason INVALID_ARGUMENT:(static_resources.clusters[0]) tlsContext: Cannot find field.) has unknown fields
Error: exit status 1
Usage:
  wasme deploy envoy <image> [--config=<filter config>] [--bootstrap=<custom envoy bootstrap file>] [--envoy-image=<custom envoy image>] [flags]
```

`wasm_filter_intro` is my compiled wasm module from Rust.